# LinkedHashMap$Entry cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, list, dictionary, classcastexception, linkedhashmap

I'm wrapped `LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<Date, Double>>` into a List with;

```
List<LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<Date, Double>>> list = new ArrayList(mainCodesMap.entrySet());
```

which `mainCodeMap` is type of `Map<String, Map<Date, Double>>`

the thing is there is no problem with list,however, when I try to get elements of list by index in a for loop like;

```
for (int i = 0; i < correMatrix.length; i++) {

    LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<Date, Double>> entryRow = list.get(i);
    LinkedHashMap<Date, Double> entryRowData = (LinkedHashMap<Date, Double>) entryRow.values();
    ..
    ..
}
```

jvm throws `ClassCastException` which says;

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

Comment: I guess I'm getting confused about something,cause I thought every element of list is also `LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<Date, Double>>`

Comment: values will return you a collection of LinkedHashMap, not a single one.

Comment: `entryRow.values()` returns a `Collection<LinkedHashMap<...>>`, not a `LinkedHashMap`...

Comment: ok guys thanks a lot I solved the issue. : ) If one of you could write your answer I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<Date, Double>>> list = new ArrayList(mainCodesMap.entrySet());
```

`mainCodesMap.entrySet` returns a `Set<Map.Entry<...>>` (not literally `...`). You then create an `ArrayList` containing these `Map.Entry`s. Because you are using the raw type `ArrayList` (instead of `ArrayList<something>`) the compiler can't catch this problem.

It looks like you actually meant this:

```
List<LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<Date, Double>>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(mainCodesMap)
```

Note: `ArrayList<>` means the compiler will automatically fill in the <>. It doesn't work in all contexts.

Comment: Actually, I changed a couple of lines,like `List<Entry<String, LinkedHashMap<Date, Double>>> list = new ArrayList(mainCodesMap.entrySet());`, so I have only entries in a list as I wanted. However, what do you mean by "It doesnt work in all contexts". Does it depend on Java version ?. And thanks for your reply anyway